# How to terminate FFMPEG running from Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

If I send SIGTERM to FFMPEG it finishes with non-zero status. I found a solution with "q" to the STDIN but it doesn't work in my case.

I try to do it this way: I launch FFMPEG from Python like this:

```py
stop_file_fd, _ = tempfile.mkstemp()
with os.fdopen(stop_file_fd, 'w+') as stop_file_fp:
    p = subprocess.Popen((
        'ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-loglevel', 'error',
        '-i', m3u8_playlist_url, '-c:v', 'copy', '-c:a', 'copy', '-f', 'flv',
        rtmp_endpoint,
    ), stdin=stop_file_fp)

    launch_another_thread(p, stop_file_fp)

    p.communicate()
```

In another thread:

```py
stop_file_fp.write('q')
os.fsync(stop_file_fp.fileno())
stop_file_fp.seek(0)
```

It seems like FFMPEG stops to stream the data, but the process doesn't exit.

**UPD.** I have created a repository with the problem reproducing: https://github.com/andre487/ffmpeg-stop-reproducing

I tried to use `p.stdin.write(b'q')`. The problem appears this way: when you call stop from a client – it works. But when you try to quite a server with `Ctrl+C` FFMPEG stops to handle data but a process is still alive.

Also I have tried `'q'.encode("GBK")` – it works the same way.

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible code sample that we can execute, verify the problem and test the solution. Why are you writing 'q' to `stop_file_fp` instead of writing `q` to `p.stdin`? The syntax is `p.stdin.write('q'.encode("GBK"))`. When `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: I have created a repository with the problem reproducing: https://github.com/andre487/ffmpeg-stop-reproducing

I tried to use `p.stdin.write(b'q')`. The problem appears this way: when you call stop from client – it works. But when you try to quite a server with `Ctrl+C` FFMPEG stops to handle data but a process still alive

Comment: Do you mean `p.stdin.write('q'.encode("GBK"))`?

Comment: No, I used `p.stdin.write(b'q')`: https://github.com/andre487/ffmpeg-stop-reproducing/blob/main/server.py#L143 Is there any difference?

Comment: I think there may be a difference in some operation systems. Try `'q'.encode("GBK")`

Comment: I have tried this. There is no difference. It works the same way on MacOS and Linux

Comment: I don't have any experience with server execution, I don't think I can help you.